# Groovy reading unicode xml file and adding to JCR but not the full text is added as present in the source file

Tags: unicode, groovy, utf-8, aem

In Groovy, using the following snippet i am parsing an xml file which contains Unicode text. But the full text is not copied to JCR nodes, only part of the characters are recognized and copied to the target JCR nodes / another file system and the remaining characters are displaying in an unrecognized format.

```
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("$currentFileLocation")
    def inputSource = new InputSource(fr)
    inputSource.setEncoding('UTF-8')
    def obj = new XmlSlurper().parse(inputSource)
    def HtmlContent = obj."Widget-HTML"."HtmlContent".getBody().text()
```

Expected should be written to the target system as : 
サービス事例のサポート ツールセットである

But it is copied as in this format : 
サービス事例�?�サ�?ート ツールセット�?��?�る

Comment: Can you add the XML to the question?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"> <widget><HtmlContent translate="y">&lt;style type="text/css"& gt; div.pChangeMainLink { background:none; } div.pChangeMainLink a { border-top:0px; padding: 6px 5px 0px 25px; } .pChangeModWrap { border:none; background:none; } .pChangeModSet { border-top:0px; } .pChangeModSet ul { list-style-type:disc; } .cModItem { margin-bottom:0px; padding-bottom:0px; } span.yellow{ color:#fa9500; } &  lt;/style& gt; & lt;!--Text Module --& gt; & lt;div class="cModItem noBottomBorder" style="margin-bottom:10px;"& gt; & lt;p& gt;サービス事例のサポート ツールセットである  etc

Comment: The problem is coming when i am saving to JCR node using the following method mentioned http://www.tothenew.com/blog/content-migration-in-aem-using-slingpostservlet/ i.e., a HTTPBuilder request HTTPBuilder client  = new HTTPBuilder("http://${hostName}:${portNumber}" as String)
  client.request(Method.POST) {
   uri.path = baseURL
   requestContentType = ContentType.URLENC
   headers.'Authorization' = "Basic ${"admin:admin".bytes.encodeBase64().toString()}"

Comment: Can you add the XML to the question? Posting half the XML as a comment is no help to anyone

Answer (score 1):

Assuming below arbitrary xml file which includes the characters mentioned by the author of this question.

**xml** file, say testutf.xml.  Note that the file is saved with `utf-8` character encoding.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<records>
    <record>
        <name>サービス事例のサポート ツールセットである</name>
    </record>
</records>
```

Here is script which reads that reads the xml file in the same encoding. Comments added appropriately in-line.

```
import groovy.xml.*
//Chang the xml file path as per your environment
def fileName = '/absolute/path/of/the/testutf.xml'
//Read file with utf-8 encoding
def contents = new File(fileName).getText('utf-8')
//parsed object
def parsedContents = new XmlSlurper().parseText(contents)
//Read the data
def nameData = parsedContents.record.name
println "Record name : $nameData"
```

**Output**

```
Record name : サービス事例のサポート ツールセットである
```

And I believe that you should be able to apply the same for your own xml instead of the above sample xml.

Comment: Thanks Rao, but the problem is coming when i am saving to JCR node using the following method mentioned tothenew.com/blog/… i.e., a HTTPBuilder request HTTPBuilder client = new HTTPBuilder("http://${hostName}:${portNumber}" as String) client.request(Method.POST) { uri.path = baseURL requestContentType = ContentType.URLENC headers.'Authorization' = "Basic ${"admin:admin".bytes.encodeBase64().toString()}"

Comment: @Senthil, not sure what you mean by JCR node.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the encoding as [`Shift_JIS`](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/82396/what-issues-lead-people-to-use-japanese-specific-encodings-rather-than-unicode/82397) they handle the specifics of the Japanese characters.

Refer to a discussion [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/82396/what-issues-lead-people-to-use-japanese-specific-encodings-rather-than-unicode/82397) on Japanese Encoding with UTF-8, UTF-16 and Shift_JS

Comment: problem is coming when i am saving to JCR node using the following method mentioned tothenew.com/blog/… i.e., a HTTPBuilder request HTTPBuilder client = new HTTPBuilder("http://${hostName}:${portNumber}" as String) client.request(Method.POST) { uri.path = baseURL requestContentType = ContentType.URLENC headers.'Authorization' = "Basic ${"admin:admin".bytes.encodeBase64().toString()}"

Comment: Can you try with `requestContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8"` and if this doesn't work then refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493195/how-to-specify-content-type-in-request-in-groovy